# removeEventListner is not working. what to do?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I have a section of sliders (created in slider revolution). When I set it to scroll by keyboard arrow keys (up and down) using slider revolution.

But it was scrolling the whole page so I used observer to prevent scroll of whole page and only the section to scroll vertically.

Now `addEventListener` is working when I intersect the section but it is not removing the event listener when I leave the section.

Please suggest why this event listener is not getting removed?

```
const abcd = () => {
  const abc = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {

      var arrow_keys_handler = function(e) {
        switch (e.code) {
          case "ArrowUp":
          case "ArrowDown":
          case "ArrowLeft":
          case "ArrowRight":
          case "Space":
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      };

      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        window.addEventListener("keydown", arrow_keys_handler, false);
        return;
      } else {
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", arrow_keys_handler, false);
        return;
      }
    });
  }, {
    threshold: 0.2
  });

  abc.observe(document.querySelector('.slider_section'));
}
```

Comment: the issue may be that `arrow_keys_handler` function is a *different* one every time that callback is called - what happens if you define it *outside* of that callback

Comment: You don't even need that forEach loop. `if (entries.some(entry => entry.isInterecting)) add else remove` Also, your code will remove or add the listener based exclusively on the last entry, which is the main reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to move the `arrow_keys_handler` declaration _out of and before_ the `forEach` loop.

Comment: @lejlun has to be moved further than that....

Comment: try replacing this window.removeEventListener("keydown", arrow_keys_handler, true);

Comment: To clarify my comment: the main issue here is a logic error, where a decision isn't based on *all* entries but instead changed over and over again, based on the current entry. THIS is the thing that has to be fixed here. The fact that the handler is declared in the wrong spot is just incidental.

Comment: i tried all you guys suggested. please anyone can edit and re-write the code in the comments. so that i can try that also and find out my mistake. It will be a great help.

Comment: Here's a state-based approach: https://pastebin.com/n4GvVPeT

Comment: Tysm for the help @ChrisG . It is working properly.